# Syntax error - Expected variable name or property but found class name

Tags: applescript

I get the syntax error below with this script. It fails in the line beginning `repeat with cell in rows`. How can I get the script to compile?

```
Expected variable name or property but found class name.
```

```
-- Declare variables
property albumDescription : ""

-- Display input box to get album description
display dialog "Enter the album description:" default answer ""
set albumDescription to text returned of result

-- Open Excel
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  activate
end tell

-- Set variables for the active sheet and range of cells
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  set sh to active sheet
  set rng to range of sh
end tell

-- Loop through each cell in the range, starting from row 2
repeat with cell in rows 2 thru (count of rows of rng) of rng
  -- Check if the cell value is not empty
  if value of cell is not "" then
    -- Update the album description for the row
    set value of cell to albumDescription
  end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are three issues:

1. All terminology which belongs to a specific application (in this case `rows`, the content of `rng` and `value`) must be inside a `tell application` block.
2. You cannot use the reserved word `cell` as a variable name. Well, you can, but you have to wrap the word in pipes (`|cell|`). However I recommend to use a different name like `aCell`
3. `range` in `set rng to...` must be `used range`

---

```
-- Declare variables
property albumDescription : ""

-- Display input box to get album description
display dialog "Enter the album description:" default answer ""
set albumDescription to text returned of result

-- Open Excel
activate application "Microsoft Excel"
    
-- Set variables for the active sheet and range of cells
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set sh to active sheet
    set rng to used range of sh
    
    -- Loop through each cell in the range, starting from row 2
    repeat with aCell in rows 2 thru (count of rows of rng) of rng
        -- Check if the cell value is not empty
        if value of aCell is not "" then
            -- Update the album description for the row
            set value of aCell to albumDescription
        end if
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

Comment: Ah! Very interesting, thank you! I get a new error though with this update "Can’t get rows 2 thru 1048576 of missing value."

Comment: hmm so it opens Excel but nothing happens in it, should we have a specific range like Q2:Q500?

Comment: It doesn't work because `aCell` is actually an entire row. You have to add a second repeat loop to iterate the cells. But this is beyond the question.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. I managed to find another way to do what I needed