# AppleScript has syntax error because of quotes, how to fix it?

Tags: excel, applescript

Thank you for helping me out. I'm trying to change a cell in column N that contains the subcategory of a music track if the code finds the track title I'm looking for in column R

```
-- Declare variables
property searchTrackTitle : ""
property newSubCategory : ""

-- Display input box to get search term
display dialog "Enter the track title that you want to search for:" default answer ""
set searchTrackTitle to text returned of result

-- Display input box to get new SubCategory
display dialog "Enter the new SubCategory that you want to use:" default answer ""
set newSubCategory to text returned of result

-- Open Excel and set variables
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    set sh to active sheet
    set rng to range "R:R" of sh
end tell

-- Loop through each cell in the range
repeat with cell in rng
    -- Check if the cell value matches the search term
    if value of cell is searchTrackTitle then
        -- Update the keywords for the track title
        set value of cell "N" of sh to newSubCategory
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: It seems [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74820812/so-i-cant-have-numbers-in-applescript) has been solved, and since it is basically the same issue as the one here, you'll hopefully have solved this one in the same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you put "end tell" before the end of your job in Excel and you try to assign variable to a class name
the right code:

```
-- Declare variables
property searchTrackTitle : ""
property newSubCategory : ""

-- Display input box to get search term
display dialog "Enter the track title that you want to search for:" default answer ""
set searchTrackTitle to text returned of result

-- Display input box to get new SubCategory
display dialog "Enter the new SubCategory that you want to use:" default answer ""
set newSubCategory to text returned of result

-- Open Excel and set variables
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    set sh to active sheet
    set rng to range "R:R" of sh
    
    -- Loop through each cell in the range
    repeat with currentCell in rng
        -- Check if the cell value matches the search term
        if value of currentCell is searchTrackTitle then
            -- Update the keywords for the track title
            set value of cell "N" of sh to newSubCategory
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```